# Questions asked in Postdoc Interviews

Tags: postdocs, job-search, interview

Generally what kind of questions are asked in a postdoc interview, especially in the area of theoretical physics?

Comment: I would ask: Please explain what you did in our PhD. What were the major findings?

Comment: Why did you choose this subject?

Comment: Voted to close because there's no general rule. Usually there's a mix of "soft" questions (e.g. tell me about a time you overcame a problem, describe how you work in a team etc) and technical discussion related to the project or your own work.